# How to resize Tawk.to mobile widget icon size

Tags: tawk.to

first of all sorry for my explanation, I'm just a beginner!
I needed help with resizing the tawk.to chat icon size on mobile devices.

It's currently like so:

```
**.tawk-min-container .tawk-button-circle.tawk-button-large {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}**
```

Should also mention that NO CSS code is working from my side, since the source is external and kind of forced..?

I need it to be something like 40px. Any suggestion to override their original code.
Probably trough php function?

Thanks in advance! :)